Was AI used in the June 2024 NHS data breach?
There is a BBC segment called "AI Decoded" in which they have convened a panel of cyber security experts. The episode is titled "Hackers expose deep cybersecurity vulnerabilities in AI". Within the first 1 minute of the episode, it smash-cuts from an ethical hacker jailbreaking LLMs to heavily implicating AI in the recent hacks at a number of NHS hospitals that utilise the company Synlab for some of their systems.
Transcribing the video:

Cyber security. How long would it take an advanced hacker to break
into the most complex, most powerful AI models that we've built? 30
minutes, as it happens. This week, the FT carried an exclusive
interview with the mysterious, faceless hacker known as Pliny the
Prompter. He is stress testing, or "jail breaking" the Large Language
Models that Microsoft, ChatGPT and Google have been building. An
ethical, online warrior who is part of the international effort to
draw attention to the shortcomings of the biggest tech companies who,
he argues, are putting profit before safety.
And if you think that is a risk somewhere in the future, think again.
Just two weeks ago, the Russian cyber criminals Qilin used
sophisticated AI tools to find their way into the NHS computers.

I have not been able to find a single source that states that AI was used in these attacks. Am I to assume that the NHS software supplier has recklessly baked an LLM into critical patient data systems, and someone jail broke them? Or are LLMs capable of generating ransomware that can attack critical infrastructure?
None of the panel on the show contest what I think is a massive conflation of very different things in that the NHS attack had nothing to do with AI, but I'm not sure if my search has been exhaustive.

I am worried that recently the terms "AI", "generative AI" and "LLM" are being conflated, so we can't be sure that the claim is related to LLMs at all.

I, too, share that worry. In my mind, there's no doubt to me that the context in which this statement is made is to implicate LLMs in the NHS ransomware attack. It is a BBC production, so I would assume some level of integrity, but I can't back up that implied approach so it just comes across as fear mongering to me. I'm not a fan of LLMs myself but I also don't like this presentation of them (unless I'm proven wrong)

Jail breaking LLMs is something entirely different than "using sophisticated AI tools" for hacking. I think the quote here is very misleading, but we should probably focus on the second paragraph alone here. The first one is not actually related at all, it's just bad journalism. Using AI tools for hacking does not necessarily imply that LLMs are a part of either the attacker or the target (though I suspect the implication here is that genAI hacking tools were used, which I personally strongly doubt).

I wonder whether currently there even are any 'sophisticated AI tools' for hacking in existence. LLMs can do some fairly clever stuff (some of the time) but it looks almost completely unrelated to what is required for hacking.

The quote conflates breaking in to steal AI with using AI to break in. It's like the difference between stealing explosives from a vault vs using explosives to blow open a vault.
